# R Programming Language merge objects within one data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have an R data frame with over 1,000 objects and each object is supposed to have a unique first element, but some of the elements appear more than once and I want to merge those objects together, so for example if I have:

```
id   frequency name
1    43        George
2    23        John
3    3         Thomas
2    17        John
4    122       James
5    32        Andrew
6    67        Martin
7    12        William
1    3         George
8    6         Zachary
6    3         Martin
9    55        Millard
```

I would want to make it into something like this (If you notice that everyone with the same id has all the same information, except for frequency) where everything stays the same except that I add all the frequencies into one sum of all of the others (there can be up to ten or so repeats for some id's:

```
id   frequency name
1    46        George
2    40        John
3    3         Thomas
4    122       James
5    32        Andrew
6    70        Martin
7    12        William
8    6         Zachary
9    55        Millard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also can be done with data.table.

```
library(data.table)
df.dt <- data.table(df)
df.dt[, .(freq=sum(freq)), by=.(id, name)]
```

**EDIT**

with comment from Arun

Comment: This only gives the frequency and name, but removes all of the other information, such as the id and all the other fields that I didn't post

Comment: How about include `id` in grouping as well: `dt[, .(frequency=sum(frequency)), by=.(id, name)]`?

Comment: @Arun, nice I was not aware of that syntax, please see edit

Comment: looks great! you could use `setDT()` to convert the data.frame directly to data.table. You might want to have a look at the [NEW html vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)...

Answer (score 1):

Very easy task with `dplyr` in combination with base R `unique`:

```
dd <- dat %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(frequency = sum(frequency))
unique(dd)
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: name

  id frequency    name
1  1        46  George
2  2        40    John
3  3         3  Thomas
4  4       122   James
5  5        32  Andrew
6  6        70  Martin
7  7        12 William
8  8         6 Zachary
9  9        55 Millard
```

Comment: The id disappeared from them in your answer, but I also have other columns that I omitted from here that I would want to keep as well (each column would be the same for each repeat occurrence)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `DF` is your data.frame, then you can use `aggregate`:

```
> result <- aggregate(frequency~id+name, sum, data=DF)
> result[order(result$id), ]
  id    name frequency
2  1  George        46
4  2    John        40
7  3  Thomas         3
3  4   James       122
1  5  Andrew        32
5  6  Martin        70
8  7 William        12
9  8 Zachary         6
6  9 Millard        55
```

Comment: `id`'s are summed up too. I think in the intent of Zachary they shouldn't be summed.

Comment: @SabDeM I think here you saw the row names. IDs are not summed up

Answer (score 1):

Using `ddply`

```
library('plyr')
ddply(dat, .(id,name), summarize, frequency = sum(frequency))

#  id    name frequency
#1  1  George        46
#2  2    John        40
#3  3  Thomas         3
#4  4   James       122
#5  5  Andrew        32
#6  6  Martin        70
#7  7 William        12
#8  8 Zachary         6
#9  9 Millard        55
```

Comment: Very clean solution with `plyr` I like it.